# Url Variables with %2f not handled by silex

Tags: php, symfony, routes, silex

I am very new to silex, but have experience with Java based MVC frameworks.

The problem I have seems to be how to accept certain special characters in URL arguments.

I have a controller defined as such:

```
$app->get('/editPage/{fileName}', function ($fileName) use ($app,$action) {
    return $app['twig']->render('edit.twig.html',$action->editPage($fileName));
});
```

and this works great for urls like:

1. /myapp/editPage/file.html
2. /myapp/editPage/file-2.html

but if I pass an encodes "/" or %2F, the route is not picked up, and I get a 404.
 1. /myapp/editPage/folder%2Ffile.html

The mod_rewrites rules should route any non-existent file paths to the index.php where silex is defined, so I am not sure what is happening.

I just need a way to capture values with "/" for this particular page. There are no conflicting childpages, so if there is a way to wildcard the path "/editPage/{.*|filename}/" or something obvious I am missing.

Comment: seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194894/flexible-dynamic-routing-with-silex

Comment: Found that related Q, but that user wants multiple distinct arguments of an unknown count, and the solutions all work towards that end.  I only have a single argument, I just need to adjust the default matching rules which seem do a hard match on "/" to break-up arguments.

Comment: The second answer seemed to suggest you could use assert http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#requirements to allow what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use assert to change the regex that is used to match the variable. If you want it to match anything, pass a very lenient regex.

eg.

```
$app = new \Silex\Application();

$app->get('/file/{filename}', function ($filename) {
        die(var_dump($filename));
})->assert('filename', '.*');

$app->run();
```

These requests

```
GET /file/a%2fb%2fc.txt
GET /file/a/b/c.txt
```

both yield

```
string 'a/b/c.txt' (length=9)
```

Comment: Maybe i have another issue as this route is still ignored, 404 returned.

Comment: This doesn't work if Apache has AllowEncodedSlashes On ( ;( )

Answer (score 3):

It's not an issue with Silex but with Apache.

Apache rejects by design encoded slashes as part of the URI for security purposes. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12993237/358813

As a workaround passing the value inside a query string is completely fine:

`http://example.com/?file=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile` will work, provided you configure Silex accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @tacone answer's, here's how I configured Silex to make it work.
I guess it's not the prettiest solution however...

The URL called should be `/get/?url=<url encoded>`

```
$siController->get('/get/', function(Application $app, $url){
    /** @var SocialIdentifier $si */
    $si = $app['social_identifier.social_identifier'];
    $result = $si->get($url);
    return $app->json($result, 200);
})
->value('url', $_GET['url']);
```