# WebTestCase, Silex and $_GET

Tags: symfony, silex, web-testing

I'm experiencing some issues on a WebTestCase using Silex: on one of my controller's action, I need a parameter passed through a normal $_GET (I have to as it's an URL, and Apaches interprets the %2F if it's outside of the query string -- see [Url Variables with %2f not handled by silex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294778/url-variables-with-2f-not-handled-by-silex/30843725#30843725)  for example)

Here's how my route is defined:

```
$controller
   ->get('/get', <controller action>)
   ->value('url', (!empty($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : false));
```

It works fine in browser, but it doesn't seem to be working inside a WebTestCase like this one: `$_GET` stays empty...

```
$client = $this->createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/get?url=' . urlencode($url));
```

**edit**

I just did a quick experiment: if I do the following in my route:

```
$controller
        ->get('/get/{url}', <action>)
        ->assert('url', '.*');
```

And this in the test:

```
$client = $this->createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/get/' . urlencode($url));
```

Everything if fine, $url gets passed to the controller... but well, it doesn't work on the browser anymore as it passes through Apache.

Comment: As a dirty trick, you can always populate the $_GET variable before calling ```$client->request(...)``` by issuing a ```$_GET['url'] = 'some url';``` (by the way which problem do you have with your second method? It should work from the browser too)

Comment: The problem is that the URL generated by this is of the form `/get/http:%2%2....`; Apache interprets that as `/get/http://` and gets lost (throws 404). There are ways to fix the problem, but you need to have access to Apache config - which I don't.

Comment: Ok so the problem is related to apache (the link you gave earlier), so I guess you're stuck with the dirty trick for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server globals (like $_GET) are populated by Apache. When running the functional test, Apache is skipped so $_GET is not populated anymore. Instead of using the server globals, you should use the Request object to extract the GET parameters. This way, the framework will intercept both the PHPUnit injected variables and the Apache injected variables; it will then make them available in your action method via a Request object that can be injected as a function parameter.

Sample how to extract the url parameter:

```
$url = $request->query->get('url');
```

Comment: Just to add a bit of info, I had to add the Request as a parameter to my controller action. Works fine now, but I'm a bit sorry that the funciton signature shows that $url is required :(