# Define Silex routes as it goes

Tags: php, symfony, silex

Is it possible to define Silex routes as the route definition goes. For instance, define the following routes depending on what the previous routes are:

```
/a/{user}/{app_name}/list/ -> /a/{user}/{app_name}/list/{id}/
/a/{user}/{app_name}/add/ -> /a/{user}/{app_name}/add/success/
/a/{user}/{app_name}/help/ -> no sub route
```

Here the **5th** route should be `{id}` when the **4th** is `list` or `success` when the **4th** is `add` or nothing when the **4th** is `help`. However I don't know how to do this in Silex:

```
$app -> get('/a/{user}/{app_name}/{action}/{sub}/', function (Silex\Application $app, $user, $app_name, $action, $sub) {
    ...
});
```

Which obviously doesn't work for all of them.

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
$app -> get('/a/{user}/{app_name}/{action}/', function (Silex\Application $app, $user, $app_name, $action) {
    if ($action == 'list') {
        $app -> get('/a/{user}/{app_name}/{action}/{id}', function (Silex\Application $app, $user, $app_name, $action, $id) {
            ...
        });
    } elseif ($action == 'add') {
        $app -> get('/a/{user}/{app_name}/{action}/success', function (Silex\Application $app, $user, $app_name, $action) {
            ...
        });
    }
});
```

The actions **list**, **add**, **help**, etc. are indefinite as they are defined by my users who create simple apps in our system. So there's no way I can directly hard code them in my code. It is only after the routing goes to a specific user app e.g. `/a/jim/cook` that the actions are available.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15214674/49318

```
$app->get('/pdf/{template}/{args}', function ($template, $args) {
    ...
})
->assert('args', '.*')
->convert('args', function ($args) {
    return explode('/', $args);
});
```